# How to define data loader in PYTorch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I Tried data Loader in tensor flow but how can I define data loader in PYtorch

## Define data loaders.

```
train_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
validation_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
```

Please someone help me

Answer (score 0):

You've generated a dataset, which is the first step to creating a dataloader:

```
batch_size = 4
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)
validation_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(validation_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)

for x,y in train_loader:
    print(x,y)
```